# How do I select columns that have the same value in a specified number of rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that contains the following 8 values: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ?, and -.
The values from 0 to 5 are characters and not numeric. For certain rows, I want to know what column values they have in common. In the data frame below, for instance, I want to know what columns have identical values for rows 3, 4, and 5. So I want it to return columns x6, x7, and x8. How do I do this in R?

```
 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8
 1  0  5  1  1  ?  0  5
 2  1  ?  1  2  5  1  -
 3  2  1  3  2  1  3  ?
 4  3  ?  4  1  1  3  ?
 5  4  0  1  ?  1  3  ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` to iterate over the columns on row 3 to 5 and see which one has a `length` of `unique` value equals 1.

```
colnames(df)[apply(df[3:5,], 2, \(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)]

[1] "x6" "x7" "x8"
```